# Java while and method

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

my only one method is here. I have a problem with this one.I want to change b value which cames 1 , 2 or 3 from the remains codes but this has to be random numbers 1, 2, 3. This code has to be working but I got the same value for b here sometimes. I debug this code with prints(system.out). Problem is while loop does not work truely. I did not understand why and I need help.
Thank you for help...

```
     public static int CheckAlmondsX(int b,int x,int y)    
     {
          if(cells[x-2][y].equals(cells[x-1][y]))
          {

           do  {
                  c=1+rnd.nextInt(3);

                } while (c==b);                   

            b=c;
           }

      return b;

      }
```

Comment: Could you describe what is your goal exactly?

Comment: What do you mean the `while` loop is not working?

Comment: I created a string array [10][10] and it has the value only 3 different the others and they will not same in the array like that [0][0]="a",[0][1]="a",[0][2]="a". I am checking this b value with this method for example  for b=1 array "a",for b=2 array "r" etc.

Comment: this while loop return sometimes same value for b but I don t want the same value.

Comment: If you are getting the same value for `b` then it is because the condition of the `if` is not being `true` in those cases.

Comment: I said the above, I looked at the whole codes everything is ok if condition is true and program enters the while loop but wrong value returns.